# how to Extract tar Files?

Tags: linux, compression, gzip, extract, tar

i want to extract tar file.
but, terminal is error output.

i want to solve the error.
could you help me?

this is terminal cmd

```
$ tar xvzf test.tar  -C /dir/
```

this is error output

```
# gzip: invalid magic
# tar: Child returned status 1
# tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: `$ tar xvf` is the universal command for all *.tar, *.tar.gz, *.tar.bz2` since year 2004 : No "xvzf" or "xvjf" required since then. And in year 2009 `*.tar.xz` was included in the automatic compression recognition. See "tar Changelog".

Comment: That may be true, but the inverse isn't.  xzvf with a .tar doesn't work.  He can either compress the archive, or use it without z.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are running tar xzvf, which extracts a compressed tar, but the filename given is tar, which is just a tar file, not compressed.  Try without the z.

`tar xvf ...`

Answer (score 0):

Put the below code into your bashrc then just :

```
UZ file.tar
```

you can also use it with zip, 7z, tar.gz, or gz.

in your bashrc:

```
UZ() {
  # Extract file name and extension separately
  f_name="$(basename "$1" | awk -F. 'BEGIN{OFS="_"} {if ($(NF-1) == "tar") {ext = $(NF-1) "." $NF; NF-=2} else {ext = $NF; NF--}; print $0}')"
  f_ext="$(echo "$1" | awk -F. '{if ($(NF-1) == "tar") {print $(NF-1) "." $NF} else {print $NF}}')"

  # Determine the last or last two dots to perform the actions
  case "$f_ext" in
    "zip")
      echo "unzipping zip to $f_name"
      mkdir "$f_name"
      unzip "$1" -d "$f_name"
      ;;
    "tar.gz" | "tgz")
      echo "unzipping tar.gz to $f_name"
      mkdir "$f_name"
      tar -zxvf "$1" -C "$f_name" --strip-components 1
      ;;
    "tar")
      echo "unzipping tar to $f_name"
      mkdir "$f_name"
      tar -xvf "$1" -C "$f_name"
      ;;
    "gz")
      echo "unzipping gz to $f_name"
      mkdir "$f_name"
      gunzip -c "$1" > "$f_name"
      ;;
    "7z")
      echo "unzipping 7z to $f_name"
      mkdir "$f_name"
      7z x "$1" -o"$f_name"
      ;;
    *)
      echo "unknown file type: $f_ext"
      ;;
  esac
}
```